# Unable to fix type 'String' not a subtype of 'bool' error in Flutter, dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I've looked at other solutions on Stackoverflow but I haven't been able to find something that worked for me. I'm basically just trying to conditionally render a String text based on whether or not a parameter called `connectionStatus` that I pass into the class of the code down below is true or not.

I get this error when I try running it on my emulator
[image]

Here's my code, I commented on where the problem is happening. Whenever I just use either `false` or `true` in the place of `connectionStatus`, like a straight boolean value, it works but as soon as I use the variable I get the error.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OtherProfile extends StatelessWidget {
  final bool connectionStatus; //Connected, request pending etc

  const OtherProfile(
      {super.key,
        required this.connectionStatus,
      });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFFFFF0E6)
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            // space between top of phone and rest of content
            const SizedBox(
              height: 90.0,
            ),

            // space between content
            const SizedBox(
              height: 24.0,
            ),

            // display main buttons
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 152,
                  height: 31,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                      backgroundColor:
                          MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.black),
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {},

                    // ------------ THIS IS WHERE MY PROBLEM IS ---------------
                    child: connectionStatus ?
                      const Text("CONNECTED")
                    :
                      const Text("CONNECT"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

---------------- EDIT -----------------------

Here is the code of the `onTap` class from the `ListTile` class I'm using to handle this:

```
onTap: () async {
  // Go to User's profile page
  // print(users.users);
  String receiverId = users.users[index]["name"];
  print(receiverId);

  String receiverUserName = users.users[index]["username"];
  String receiverFullName = users.users[index]["name"];
  String receiverProfileImg = users.users[index]["profile_image"];
  bool receiverConnectionStatus = false;
  int receiverNConnections = 45;

  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => OtherProfile(
      userName: receiverUserName, 
      fullName: receiverFullName, 
      profileImage: receiverProfileImg, 
      connectionStatus: receiverConnectionStatus, 
      nConnections: receiverNConnections)
    )
  );
},
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you're calling this screen.

Comment: Moreover, I can see this `final bool connectionStatus; //Connected, request pending etc` this means you're trying to pass String to bool variable. Please check variable declaration and initialization in dart.

Comment: a lot of the time connection status, is not a is or is not connected, it is typically a Pending, Active, Closed, Failed, etc. so would need to map those to a true or false.